# Joint Position Controller Plugin doesn't subscribe to any topics

Tags: gazebo, joint, gazebo-11, gazebo-ignition, joints

I am trying to get the Joint Position Controller working with either Gazebo Fortress of Gazebo Garden. For the former I start the demo simulation with:

```
ign gazebo -v 4 joint_position_controller.sdf
```

Then check for available topics with:

```
ign topic -l
```

And none of the joint command topics are listed.

I see equivalent results with Gazebo Garden, and with the Joint Controller Plugin, and I have also reproduced this with all of the demo worlds that come with those versions of Gazebo and also with NAO Joint Control here https://fuel.ignitionrobotics.org/1.0/OpenRobotics/worlds/NAO%20joint%20control

Interestingly, for that last one, the GUI does allow me to control the joints.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-transport/issues/263), fixed by [this PR](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-transport/pull/379).

So this will be fixed in the upcoming Harmonic release, as well as in Garden (and I assume also Fortress), when updated packages are released.
If you can't wait for that, you can compile from source per [these instructions](https://gazebosim.org/docs/garden/install_ubuntu_src).

Note though that only the topic *list* is affected. I.e. it is not because they are not listed, that there are no listeners. If you publish to the correct topic, it should work just fine. If you're not sure about the correct topic name: often the subscription topic is listed in the debug log output.

Comment: Great, thank you!